# Add a pushbutton to resource file in Win32

Tags: visual-c++, win32gui

How can I add a pushbutton to resource file in Win32?
All examples I found shows how to in Dialog Window or modal, but how about main Window?

I've this sample:

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE 0, 0, 239, 66
    STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
    CAPTION "My About Box"
    FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
    BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON "&OK",IDOK,174,18,50,14 //tried to add this in resource, but unsuccessful
    //more code
END
```

Comment: Window doesn't have resource. Add button in the code.

Comment: But I can add a menu and icon...

Comment: Yes, window can use menu and icon from resources. But unlike a dialog, it doesn't have its own resource.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. You should answer instead commenting, so I vote you up.

Comment: Side note: having the client area exactly filled by a border-less and title-less DialogBox may be COOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the button from the code. Unlike a dialog, window doesn't have its own resource. It uses resources to create menu and icon, but window client area doesn't use any resource.